# count(*) error in cassandra

Tags: csv, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Am loading the so called COMPANY table successfully into Cassandra. (company.csv) 
After loading I get the message "394 rows imported in 1.999 seconds."

When I count them using "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COMPANY;" am getting only 2 rows.

I have tried dropping the tables & creating again. Even dropped the whole Keyspace & Created again, but the problem still remains same.
Any solution for this?

Comment: Please share your table (column family) definition and a couple rows of input. It's probably as @RussS describes, and this info should show it.

Answer (score 2):

Inserts and updates are the same in Cassandra so if you have duplicate records for your key they will overwrite previously inserted data.

Example

```
Given Key (x)

x,y,z
1,1,1
1,2,2
1,3,3
```

The only record in Cassandra would be

```
1,3,3
```

As the other records would have been overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

What's your replication factor? What read consistency are your specifying? If your replication factor is RF, write consistency is W and read consistency is R, then R + W > RF will give you immediate consistency. If your replication factor is 3, W is 1 and R is one, then it might very well be that you're writing to one replica and reading from another.

On a different note, what's your primary key? It it's only the CompanyId (or similar) then a SELECT COUNT(*) would be a terrible query. If you only have 394 companies, then it might be better to have a single partition for all companies and have all companies as rows. Your primary key in this case might be:

```
Primary key (CompanyDummySameForAll int, CompanyId int)
```

This will mean all companies will be stored in a single partition (the one with id CompanyDummySameForAll), and all other company data as rows in that partition. You can then query by:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from TableName where CompanyDummySameForAll = 1;
```

It'll still not be a great query (SELECT COUNT(*)'s aren't in general), but it'll be way better. And with 394-ish entries, should be fine.